# Failed at the @coreui/coreui-pro-react-admin-template-starter@2.1.2 start script Error while Starting npm

Tags: reactjs, core-ui

I am Trying to run a project in react. so I started to install npm and then I am trying to start the project by using `npm start`, I am getting the error like

**Error :**

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @coreui/coreui-pro-react-admin-template-starter@2.1.2 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @coreui/coreui-pro-react-admin-template-starter@2.1.2 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\chand\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-03T05_34_54_292Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\chand\Downloads\iotsaas_portal_react-master\iotsaas_portal_react-mast
```

Can you help me to solve this. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

go to your project directory (same with where you run 'npm install'), and try running 'npm install react-scripts' and also please add a complete screenshot of error from top to bottom